# Access and refresh tokens in spring boot. Is this safe?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, refresh-token

I am building my first web app with spring boot and react. Right now I am focusing on the security aspect. The app uses jwt tokens. When the user logs in, the backend responds with a short-lived access token in the Authorization header along with a long-lived refresh token that is stored in a http-only cookie. The access token is then stored in local storage and used to make subsequent requests. The cookie's (cookie contains refresh token) path is set to the endpoint that is responsible for refreshing the access token, so that it wont be sent along with each request made by the fronted. If the access token expires then the backend responds with 401 status and the frontend makes a request to the refresh endpoint.

Is this approach valid considering its a showcase app or should I use OAuth2 and "backend for frontend" or "BFF"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this approach valid considering its a showcase app or should I use OAuth2 and "backend for frontend" or "BFF"?

We can't say, its all about who you are show casing it for.

If it is in regards of showing that you can security i would definitely not show it as it will only show that you get your knowledge from following poor blogposts and that you have no real knowledge about why you should not build such logins in production environments.

The [OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics) document recommends against using the *Implicit flow* entirely because of risks of returning access tokens in an HTTP redirect without any confirmation that it has been received by the client.

If you are explicitly using JWT-tokens there are other serious risks to consider when handing out tokens straight to browsers.

There is no such implementation in Spring Security, and there is good reason for it.

- You can not logout the user, deleting the token in the browser does not mean the user is logged out. If someone else has the token its still usable.
- Tokens can only expire
- No possibility of blocking users
- Can't logout "all devices"
- Tokens can be stolen through XSS attacks
- No safe way of storing tokens in the browser
- if user is tricked into calling http and not https the token can be stolen from requests.
- There has been several vulnerabilities in JWT libraries the past years

And the list goes on.

JWTs were meant to be used within private networks, to reduce the number of requests to issuers. They were supposed to be short lived (minutes) to execute one shot requests. They where never meant to replace sessions.

Springs [Implementation guidelines for Browser-Based Apps (SPA)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297) recommends private clients like a BFF.

The big companies like Google, Facebook, etc. don't expose tokens to browsers, they use BFF patterns with cookies in the client mostly following the OpenID connect standard.

So if you are planning to show that you know security, i would show proper security.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide such a thorough answer. Your insights have been helpful. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

The `access/refresh token`  is totally fine! you can Oauth2.0 alongside only if you want to let your users be authenticated by other identity providers services like Google.

Comment: this answer is completely missleading, the oauth2 implicit flow has been deprecated by oauth2 which means giving out tokens straight to browsers is not recommended. There are several serious security issues with handing out tokens straight to browsers, for instance XSS attacks stealing tokens, not being able to hard logout users, MITM attacks stealing tokens. etc